# How do I confirm extence/non-existence of hard drive on an old iMac?

Tags: imac

How do I open the case on an original (purple) iMac.  I want to verify whether or not there is a hard drive in the computer.  What safety precautions should I observe?  Apple profiler, run from the install disk does not find a hard drive, but I want to be sure. It's a PPC G3.

Answer (score 1):

If this iMac of yours is, as i believe, a revision C iMac (revision A and B were all Bondy Blue), then there you can find [a guide](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iMac+G3+Model+M4984+Hard+Drive+Replacement/1563) on iFixit.com about how to reach and replace its hard drive.

Comment: I know it’s bad taste to only post a link, but summarizing doesn’t make much sense here, and reproducing the entire guide (not sure if possible, as it is distributed under Creative Commons BY-NC-SA, and Stack Exchange material is BY-SA only) would be impractical at best.